# What is the best way to write java DTO for dynamic json keys

Tags: java, json, data-structures, jax-rs, dto

I am writing a jax-rs based rest API where my response would contain dynamic json keys. In the response below json keys Tom, Harry are dynamic and there can be many more. What would be the best way to write a java DTO to represent structure and be able have dynamic employee names?

```
    "employee":{  
      "Tom":{  
         "id":"23974",
         "name":"Tom L",
         "jobRole":"Associate",
         "contact":{  
            "phone":"8889993332",
            "address":"some address"
         },
         "peers":[  
            "peer1",
            "peer2"
         ]
      },
      "Harry":{  
         "id":"34234",
         "name":"Harry S",
         "jobRole":"Associate",
         "contact":{  
            "phone":"3459993332",
            "address":"some address"
         },
         "peers":[  
            "peer1",
            "peer2"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Map of Maps should work for you

Comment: "dynamic json keys" = `Map` --- That means that the type of the `employee` field of the root object is a `Map<String, Employee>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the below class:

```
class EmployeeDetails {
      private Map<String, Employee> Employee;
}

class Employee {
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private String jobRole;
     private Contact contact;
     private List<String> peers;
 }

 class Contact {
    private String phone;
    private String address;
  }
```

Comment: Except that `details` field should be named `employee`